# Solenoid valve part

Tags: solenoid, solenoid-valve

Noob question, what is the pink one in the solenoid? Can it be bought separately[image]? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pink parts are female spade connectors with (in this case) a pink cover.

They can be crimped to wire, and they can be found at your local hardware store, or on-line.

[image]